# JMX configuration for sonarqube

Tags: for-loop, configuration, sonarqube, jmx

Im trying to connect JMX remote access. I configured sonar.properties file mentioned in the [sonarqube](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/instance-administration/monitoring/) doc’s like below

JMX WEB - 10443/10444

`sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=10443 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=10444 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/opt/sonarsource/sonar/conf/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/opt/sonarsource/sonar/conf/jmxremote.access`

then I created jmxremote.access and password files. After that restart sonarqube.
I’m unable to connect remote access from Jconsole ?

[Jconsole connection failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTHpM.png)